# LaTeX code for boxes used in smartdiagram package

Tags: tikz-pgf, smartdiagram

I want to draw boxes with same color code and font like those used in the smartdiagram package. Can someone help provide some hint in doing this. See the diagram. [image]

Comment: Look at the sources, which are available online.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer will show you how to find the information you ask for in the sources (for v0.3b, dated 2016/12/23, distributed with TL2018).

---

Firstly look at the style file which says (only relevant content for you):

```
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{core.definitions}
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{core.styles}
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{core.commands}
```

So you have to search the three library files. You will be able to spot the following relevant definitions. So starting with the colors:

```
\@namedef{color@1}{red!40}
\@namedef{color@2}{cyan!40}
\@namedef{color@3}{blue!40}
\@namedef{color@4}{green!40}
\@namedef{color@5}{orange!40}
\@namedef{color@6}{yellow!40}
\@namedef{color@7}{magenta!40}
\@namedef{color@8}{brown!40}
\@namedef{color@9}{violet!40}
\@namedef{color@10}{teal!40}
```

And this describes your diagram:

```
   \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center,let hypenation}]

   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}  {\global\let\maxsmitem\xi}

   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
   \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xi}}
   \IfStrEq{\option}{horizontal}{% true-horizontal-flow diagram
     \path let \n1 = {int(0-\xi)}, \n2={0+\xi*\sm@core@modulexsep} in
         node[module,drop shadow] (module\xi) at +(\n2,0) {\smitem};
   }{% false-horizontal-flow diagram
     \path let \n1 = {int(0-\xi)}, \n2={0-\xi*\sm@core@moduleysep} in
         node[module,drop shadow] (module\xi) at +(0,\n2) {\smitem};
   }
   }%

   % arrows omitted
   \end{tikzpicture}
```

Hence you will see that you need

```
\tikzset{module/.style={%
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/smart diagram/module shape},
      thick,
      draw=\sm@core@bordercolor,
      top color=white,
      bottom color=\col,
      text=\sm@core@textcolor,
      text width=\sm@core@moduletextwidth,
      minimum width=\sm@core@modulewidth,
      minimum height=\sm@core@moduleheight,
      font=\sm@core@modulefontsize,
      \sm@core@borderdecoration
   },
   % arrows omitted
}
```